# A cell complex homeomorphic to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

**Proposition**. If $X$ is a finite $n$-dimensional cell complex, such that each $(n-1)$-cell is contained in exactly two $n$-cells, then $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$.

This statement sounds quite reasonable and easy to convince oneself for the 1-dimensional case. But I am not sure on how to go about proving this statement.

**Edit**: I realized the statement is not true. But I am still interested in knowing if we can limit ourselves to some spaces. For example in dimension 2 maybe this is always a closed surface (so it would be characterized by the genus).

Comment: It can be any manifold.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek *any*? How do you claim such generality

Comment: A simplicial (or other cell) complex satisfying this property (plus some very mild connectivity condition) is sometimes called a pseudomanifold. OK, I don't want to claim "any", not to get into some strange issues, but surely more than spheres. All "nicely" triangulated manifolds in any case. Especially in the 2d case, any triangulation of the torus or any other surface has this property.

Comment: I think Michal is correct: any triangulated surface has such decomposition. Maybe there's a mistake, and real statement should be: for any $0< k \leq n$ each $(k-1)$-cell is contained in exactly two $k$-cells?

Comment: Yes, I realized now you guys are right. This is not true. I was trying to characterize what type of spaces we get with this condition. I think it will always be something that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Do you agree?

Comment: No. Even for $n=2$ not every surface is embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In general every $n$-dimensional (simplicial) complex embeds in dimension $2n+1$, and for manifolds $2n$.

Comment: Now I remembered. This is exactly the class of simplicial complexes known as "weak pseudomanifolds". You can google around for what is known about them. They are of some interest in combinatorial algebraic topology. In particular if you assume shellability or something similar then you can get your conclusion about being homeomorphic to a ball, I think. But maybe I'm jumping too far. And, generally, you should think "at least as general as manifolds".

Comment: Even in 2d you may not get a surface.

Comment: The examples are kind of wild, not sure what you might want to say about them. If you start with any $n$-complex of this type, and make identifications of cells of dimension $\le n-2$, you will get another complex of this type. For instance, start with any cell structure on a surface and make identifications of $0$-cells; all 2-dimensional examples are of this type. Or start with any cell structure on a 3-manifold and make identifications of cells of the 1-skeleton; but now it would be hard to say anything about all 3-dimensional examples.